# Unique properties of pure Imaginary numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

Are there any non trivial properties unique of the imaginary numbers?

By trivial I mean stuff like $\bar a=-a$.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what would qualify as non-trivial.

Comment: For example $z^2 \in (-\infty, 0)$?

Comment: Like $\lvert e^a \rvert = 1$ precisely when the real part of $a$ is $0$?

Comment: The title says "pure imaginary numbers" but the body of the question says "imaginary numbers". Which is it?

Comment: @bof Pure I meant a complex number that has real part = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|e^z| = 1$ for $z$ purely imaginary.