# If $f$ is holomorphic then integral of $f'(z)\overline{f(z)}$ on a close line is an imaginary number.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $f$ is holomorphic then integral of $f'(z)\overline{f(z)}$ on a close line is an imaginary number.

What I have done so far: $\frac{d}{dt}[|φ(t)|^2]=2Re(φ'(t)\overline{φ(t)})$, and since the real part of the function has an antiderivative in a closed line then it is equal to zero. However, I haven't found a way to prove that the integral of the imaginary part of the above function is non-zero.

Comment: what do you mean by a "close line"?

Comment: The integral can be zero (e.g. for $f(z) = 0$), and zero is an imaginary number as well.

Comment: The answer on that thread is pretty much what I have found. So just to make sure I got it right:I have proven that the integral has definitely a real part equal to zero. So it is either an imaginary number or zero. What I don't understand is the case where the imaginary part is also zero. We just assume that zero is an imaginary number(I 've never heard this one that's why I am asking)?

Comment: Compare [Is $0$ an imaginary number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2221033/42969). – There may be different conventions whether zero is called an “imaginary number” or not, but in this concrete case the integral definitely *can* be equal to zero.

Comment: Ok I think I am good! Thank you for your help!