# Is $0$ pure imaginary, real, or both?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers

Is $0$ considered pure imaginary? Of course $0 \in \mathbb R$ and is therefore real.  But $0$ seems to be pure imaginary as well, in the sense that any property I can think of which is true if a number is imaginary (e.g. $z = - \bar z$) applies to $0$ as well.

Another example: Imaginary numbers are closed under addition *only* if $0$ is pure imaginary.

What properties of pure imaginary numbers (or matrices) are there, and which apply to $0$? Do any not?

Should we conclude that $0$ is both real and imaginary?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at : [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221033/is-0-an-imaginary-number).

Comment: 0 is an integer

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy, but also a quaternion.

Comment: $i0=0$ so both...

Comment: Eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are either 0 or real; of an antisymmetric matrix either 0 or imaginary.  This suggests that 0 is both real and imaginary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the term *pure imaginary* changed over the years and became absurd. Currently, $0$ is both real and pure imaginary, but originally only the numbers of the form $bi$ with a real $b\ne 0$ were pure imaginary.

Moreover, currently, the *imaginary part* of $a + bi$, with $a$ and $b$ real, is $b$, which is absurd, since $b$ is real and, moreover, is not a *part* of $a + bi$ in the normal sense. Originally, the imaginary part of $a + bi$ was $bi$.

(Note also that the "imaginary part" in the modern sense is not well-defined since the number $i$ is not well defined: which of the two square roots of $-1$ is it? There is no such problem with the original imaginary part.)

See Eduard Study and Élie Cartan. *Nombres complexes.* French. In : Arithmétique et algèbre. T. 1 : Arithmétique. Sous la dir. de Jules Molk. Encyclopédie des sciences mathématiques pures et appliquées Tome I. Paris : Gauthier-Villars, avr. 1908, p. 329-468.

Comment: That the imgainary part is a real number is not absurd , it is the real number occuring at the $i$-summand. But that $0$ is considered also purely imaginary , is indeed absurd. Mathematics should not be a question of authorities (whoever invented it this way) , but a question of reasonable definitions.

Comment: @Peter, I agree that mathematical truths (as opposed to "conventions") are not determinable by "authorities". :) But, yes, some personalities who find affection for mathematics _do_ want absolute and eternal "definitions". I tell my students that _context_ is the universal essential to understand terminology. I'm old enough that I've noticed "drift" both in "standard English" and "standard mathematical nomenclature". One hilarious case is that $1$ was once-upon-a-time considered to be a prime, but eventually it was not. So I tell students, "$1$ used to be prime, but now isn't". :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Some people (mostly however non-mathematicians) still consider $1$ to be prime. For example also Joerg Resag who wrote an excellent German site ("Die Grenzen der Berechenbarkeit") and even Carl Sagan. Good that in this case , finally $1$ was NOT considered to be prime since then we would not have unqiue prime factorization.

Comment: @Peter, "That the imgainary part is a real number is not absurd" -- i do not see why. $b$ is not even a "part" of $a + ib$ in the usual sense (but $ib$ is).

Comment: @Peter $1$ being a prime is *irrelevant* to unique factorization. The current formulation is *unique* with a bunch of caveats already. Namely, up to reordering of the factors, and the factors required to be relatively prime. Having $1$ prime would only add a bit more to it, which has to be added anyway, in general UFD.

Comment: @NDB, prime numbers are off-topic here, but I would mention that IMO the prime numbers should not be characterized by such an advanced theorems as unique factorisation, but by their position in the divisibility lattice, where they are obviously one level above $1$.

Comment: @Alexey That's how you get the concept of irreducible, until you realize it is not quite the same.

Comment: [Irreducible and prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element#Relationship_with_prime_elements)

Comment: @paulgarrett, I'd say that you need to make your mind and stop following the "drift." :)

Comment: @Alexey, indeed! :)